# What to do when archive logs are lost/corrupted that are not backed up

Tags: oracle-11g, logs

All recently generated archive logs were corrupted but datafiles are fine.What if recently generated archives corrupted and the archives backup is not available, so what would be the strategy to resolve the issue and is there any possible way to rectify the archive log corruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as your recovery thread is interrupted, making it impossible to recover from an earlier backup to the current time, the remedy is to take a backup before something more serious happens.

Next investigate how the archives became corrupted and solve that.

Backups are of no importance, important is the ability to recover from a disaster and for that backups or physical standby databases can be very convenient to have.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as your instance is down ; start recovery to its latest current time by getting SCN from control file and try to get any of old archive log and start recovery with reset log option.

After starting instance try to investigate the basic reason of corruption and malfunctioning of system.

Answer (score 0):

> All recently generated archive logs were corrupted but datafiles are fine.

*How* did the corruption occur?

Have you eliminated the *source* of this corruption?
If not, then you might well be doing this *all over again* and, next time, it might take out your Data Files as well.

> what would be the strategy to resolve the issue ...

Take a Level 0 Backup as soon as possible.

Your recovery position at this point is nothing more recent that the last, "good" ArchiveLog.  That's *probably* not good enough to meet your Recovery Objectives.

> is there any possible way to rectify the archive log corruption.

Short answer: No.

ArchiveLogs are a proprietary binary file format to which "something" (unknown) has happened.
I doubt even anyone at Oracle themselves would take on *that* "challenge".

Trash them and move on.